# Vectorized operations on cell arrays

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This post was triggered by [following discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498332/storing-strings-of-different-sizes-in-a-matlab-array/6498365#6498365) on whether cell arrays are "normal arrays" and that vectorizaton does not work for cell arrays.

I wonder why following vectorization syntax is not implemented in MATLAB, what speaks against it:

```
>> {'hallo','matlab','world'} == 'matlab'
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

internally it would be equivalent to

```
[{'hallo'},{'matlab'},{'world'}] == {'matlab'}
```

because MATLAB knows when to cast, following works:

```
[{'hallo','matlab'},'world']
```

Cell array is [an array of pointers](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=858637&tstart=0). If both left and right side point to equal objects, `isequal('hallo','hallo')` returns as expected true, then why MATLAB still does not allow topmost example?

**I know** I can use `strmatch` or `cellfun`.

**SUMMARY**:

- operator `==` which is required for vectorization in above example is `eq` and not `isequal` (other operators are `<` which is `lt`, etc.)
- `eq` is built-in for numeric types, for all other types (like strings) MATLAB gives as freedom to overload this (and other) operators.
- operator vectorization is thus well possible with cell arrays of defined type (like string) but not by default for any type.
- function vectorization like `myFun( myString )` or `myFun( myCellOfStrings )`, is also possible, you have just to implement it internally in `myFun`. Functions `sin(val)` and `sin(array)` work also not by witchcraft but because both cases are implemented internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, `==` is **not** the same as [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html). The function that gets called when you use `==` is [`eq`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eq.html), and the scope of each of those is different.

For e.g., in `eq(A,B)`, if `B` is a scalar, the function checks *each* element of `A` for equality with `B` and returns a logical vector.

```
eq([2,5,4,2],2)

ans =

     1     0     0     1
```

However, `isequal(A,B)` checks if `A` is *identically* equal to `B` in all aspects. In other words, MATLAB cannot tell the difference between `A` and `B`. Doing this for the above example:

```
isequal([2,5,4,2],2)

ans =

     0
```

I think what you *really* intended to ask in the question, but didn't, is:

> "Why is `==` not defined for cell arrays?"

Well, a simple reason is: Cells were not intended for such use. You can easily see how implementing such a function for cells can quickly get complicated when you start considering individual cases. For example, consider

```
{2,5,{4,2}}==2
```

What would you expect the answer to be? A reasonable guess would be

```
ans = {1,0,0}
```

which is fair. But let's say, I disagree. Now I'd like the equality operation to walk down nested cells and return

```
ans = {1,0,{0,1}}
```

Can you disagree with this interpretation? Perhaps not. It's equally valid, and in some cases that's the behavior you want.

This was just a simple example. Now add to this a mixture of nested cells, different types, etc. within the cell and think about handling each of those corner cases. It quickly becomes a nightmare for the developers to implement such a functionality that can be *satisfactorily used by everyone*.

So the solution is to overload the function, implementing only the specific functionality that *you* desire, for use in your application. MATLAB provides a way to do that too, by creating an `@cell` directory and defining an `eq.m` for use with cells the way *you* want it. Ramashalanka has demonstrated this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499296/vectorized-operations-on-cell-arrays/6499764#6499764).

Answer (score 5):

There are many things that would seem natural for MATLAB to do that they have chosen not to. Perhaps they don't want to consider many special cases (see below). You can do it yourself by overloading. If you make a directory `@cell` and put the following in a new function `eq.m`:

```
function c = eq(a,b)
if iscell(b) && ~iscell(a)
    c = eq(b,a);
else
    c = cell(size(a));
    for n = 1:numel(c)
        if iscell(a) && iscell(b)
            c{n} = isequal(a{n},b{n});
        else
            c{n} = isequal(a{n},b);
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can do, e.g.:

```
>> {'hallo','matlab','world'} == 'matlab'
ans =     [0]    [1]    [0]

>> {'hallo','matlab','world'} == {'a','matlab','b'}
ans =     [0]    [1]    [0]

>> {'hallo','matlab','world'} == {'a','dd','matlab'}
ans =     [0]    [0]    [0]

>>  { 1, 2, 3 } == 2
ans =     [0]    [1]    [0]
```

But, even though I considered a couple of cases in my simple function, there are lots of things I didn't consider (checking cells are the same size, checking a multi-element cell against a singleton etc etc).

I used `isequal` even though it's called with `eq` (i.e. ==) since it handles `{'hallo','matlab','world'} == 'matlab'` better, but really I should consider more cases.

(EDIT: I made the function slightly shorter, but less efficient)

Answer (score 2):

This is not unique to strings.  Even the following does not work:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } == 2
```

Cell arrays are *not* the same as "normal" arrays: they offer different syntax, different semantics, different capabilities, and are implemented differently (an extra layer of indirection).

Consider if `==` on cell arrays were defined in terms of `isequal` on an element-by-element basis.  So, the above example would be no problem.  But what about this?

```
{ [1 0 1], [1 1 0] } == 1
```

The resulting behaviour wouldn't be terribly useful in most circumstances.  And what about this?

```
1 == { 1, 2, 3 }
```

And how would you define this?  (I can think of at least three different interpretations.)

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } == { 4, 5, 6 }
```

And what about this?

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } == { { 4, 5, 6 } }
```

Or this?

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } == { 4; 5; 6 }
```

Or this?

```
{ 1, 2, 3 } == { 4, 5 }
```

You could add all sorts of special-case handling, but that makes the language less consistent, more complex, and less predictable.

Comment: @Mikhail: To which part are you asking "really"?

Comment: come on, "an extra layer of indirection" says nothing why it would not work!

Comment: @Mikhail: That extra layer of indirection means that at the implementation level, *every single* piece of code that operates on cell arrays works fundamentally differently to a function that operates on normal arrays.

Comment: I am asking why MATLAB has not implemented that feature, your answer is "MATLAB has not implemented that feature because cell array is not a double array". Please edit your answer so that it would contain added value and I will be pleased to upvote it!

Comment: @Mikhail: My answer gives the reason: "Cell arrays are not the same as normal arrays."  That is the reason that `==` is not defined.  So my answer correctly answers the question!  What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @Oli: I (and SO community) need a constructive answer like that of Ramashalanka or a clear answer like that of yoda. Sorry, I do not know what you mean if you do not write it down.

Comment: @Mikhail: So you'd consider my answer constructive if I simply added the words "so it doesn't make sense, in general"?  That's the only difference between my answer and @Ramashalanka's.

Comment: Why it does not make sense? Would you not like to write `ind = {'aa','bb','cc'} == 'bb'` instead of `cellfun(...)` machinery?

Comment: @Mikhail: Because the semantics are not consistent (I already mentioned the semantics).  If it's examples that you need, I can happily add them to my answer.

Comment: @Oli: you say cell and double arrays are different. But the goal is to make different pieces of system as consistent and similar as possible, for example the COM interface for Windows. The goal is to make Excel, Word and Powerpoint COM interface as similar as possible.

Comment: @Mikhail: You're arguing for adding a certain piece of Do What I Mean to Matlab.  But there's always a point where the gains of Do What I Mean are outweighed by the costs of "Oops, I Didn't Mean *That*".

Comment: @achelper: Beautifully phrased!

Comment: @Oli: I would say that Ramashalanka demonstrates that cell and double arrays works the same! The minor point is that `iseq` is build-in for double types but not for cells because there is many different ways to compare arbitrary objects (e.g. lowercase for strings)

Comment: @Mikhail: It demonstrates the exact opposite.  The fact that you need a load of special cases to achieve "intuitive" behaviour means that the behaviour must be inconsistent.  (Imagine all the extra special cases that would be needed for multi-dimensional cell arrays, or cell arrays of cell arrays, etc.).

Comment: @aschepler: what is wrong with `ind = {'aa','bb','cc'} == 'bb'`, why it could be ambiguous?

Comment: @Oli: cell arrays are like normal arrays, `[1, 2, 3] == [4, 5]` do not work either!

Comment: @Mikhail: I think you've missed the point, which is that in your hypothetical scenario where `==` is defined on cell arrays, you'd need to choose a behaviour for `{ 1, 2, 3 } == { 4, 5 }`.

Comment: @Oli: The answer is simple, I choose error, like its double counterpart. This behavior would be logical and consistent.

Comment: @Mikhail: Then that behaviour would be inconsistent with the premise, which is that `==` on cell arrays would be an element-wise `isequal` against the RHS.  (i.e. what about `{ { 4, 5 }, 2, 3 } == { 4, 5 }`?)

Comment: @Oli: Nested comparison makes no sense, therefore relying on  `isequal( { 4, 5 }, 4)` returns `false` as expected. Your example with deifferent >1 length on both sides makes anyway no sense - it should throw an error

Comment: @Oli: wouldn't you like to write `ind = {'aa','bb','cc'} == 'bb'`?

Comment: @Mikhail: Why does it not make sense?  We've said that `==` should be equivalent to `isequal`.  So we would expect `{ A, B, C } == A` to equate to `[1 0 0]`.  No?  Whichever way you choose, the behaviour is inconsistent.  And that's just one out of the 6 examples I've given.  My point is not that I expect *you* to come up with a solution to all of these.  Instead, my point is that it's impossible for the developers of Matlab to come up with a solution that everybody would find consistent, because cell arrays fundamentally aren't designed for this.

Comment: @Mikhail: You can't keep asking about your *particular* example, whilst ignoring all the others!

Comment: @Oli: Inconsistent to what? Both sides are cell arrays. They have different lengths. Result is error like `[1, 2, 3] == [4, 5]` even before comparing elements. If it had the same length then result would be an array of logicals of the same length

Comment: @Mikhail: It's inconsistent with the idea that `{ A, B, C } == A` should work.

Comment: @Oli:you need a better example to demonstrate your point. `{ A, B, C } == A` is consistent because it is a normal array `[A, B, C] == A` where elements happen to be of type cell and not double.

Comment: @Mikhail: It's the perfect example.  You'd have to choose between `{ A, B, C } == A` being consistent and always giving `[1 0 0]` (and so being unintuitive to you), or it sometimes throwing an error depending on the type of `A` (and so being inconsistent).

Comment: @Oli: see my question, I edited it, vectorization works for cell arrays! Operators must be overloaded manually but then it works like for any normal array!

Comment: @Mikhail: I haven't mentioned vectorization anywhere here.

Comment: @Oli: vectorization was the main reason why for you cell arrays are not normal arrays, see the other post

Comment: @Mikhail: Indeed, it was.  But that was a different issue.  (And IMHO, hiding a Matlab `for` loop inside a function does not equal vectorization.)

Comment: @Oli: the logic is following: `{ A, B, C } == A` with `A` being a cell is equivalent to `{ X, B, C } == {I J}` where `X = {I J}`. This is `[1, 2, 3] == [4, 5]` again

Comment: @Oli: MATLAB is being more and more JITed. CPU when processing LAPACK does GOTO. Intel has parallel instructions but that is an implementation detail viewed form MATLAB. The important thing IMO is that array insertion, access, delete is always `X(ind)` for `X` being double, cell or struct array.

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes, so you're choosing intuition over consistency.  That's fine.  But I hope you can see that your decision was arbitrary, and that the language designers want to make as few arbitrary decisions as possible.

Comment: @Oli: no, it is not intuition, if you see a cell array like a normal array then I described the same algorithm which is used for doubles. Consistency is the main objective.

Comment: @Mikhail: That may be consistent with normal arrays (in this particular case) , but it's not self-consistent.  Every time you introduce a special case like this (it's special because it deviates from a simple rule), it would need to be fully documented.  The more documentation and special cases there are, the harder the function is to use.  I came up with 6 special cases in a few minutes, there are probably lots more that I haven't thought of.

Comment: @Oli: your example `{ 1, 2, 3 } == { { 4, 5, 6 } }` in "normal array" form is `[X,Y,Z] == [K]` where `K` happens to have another type as left-hand side elements (cell vs. string). Guidance for this behavior is already defined in MATLAB - comparing different types `5==struct()` throws an error.

Comment: @Oli: I do not see any special case, I use only the "normal array" logic as defined also for double arrays

Comment: @Mikhail: It's a special case, because it cannot be explained by a simple rule.  You cannot simply say "it's the same as for normal arrays", because in normal arrays, `[ A B C ] == A` equates to `[1 0 0]`.  You have to say "it's like normal arrays, when the RHS is a scalar.  When the RHS is a cell array, it's different.  When the RHS is a column, it's different.  When the LHS is a scalar, it's different.  When the RHS contains cell arrays, it's different."

Comment: @Oli: in my last example `5==struct()` you will say - here we are again using vectorized version of operator `==`. But this is different because only scalar is accepted, if it produces an array then an error must be thrown because return argument is expected to be a scalar element

Comment: @Mikhail: If `{ 1, 2, 3 } == { { 4, 5, 6 } }` throws an error, then that's inconsistent.  We're supposed to be comparing using `isequal`.

Comment: @Oli: why column vs, row should be different as in "normal array", it is like `[1,2,3] == [3;4;5]`

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes, I know that.  But you are advocating `isequal` (otherwise it doesn't work with strings).

Comment: @Oli: OK now I see that `{ A, B, C } == X` is a bad idea for general case (that's why it in not available in MATLAB). But you have to admit that cell arrays behave like normal arrays given a custom `iseq` implementation and for vectorization with operators/functions in general.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is: cell arrays can store different types of variables in different cells. Thus the operator `==` can't be defined well for the entire array. It is even possible for a cell to contain another cell, further exacerbating the problem.

Think of `{4,'4',4.0,{4,4,4}} == '4'`. what should be the result? Each type evaluates in different way.

Comment: you are wrong, see my question, result would be equivalent to `cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,4),{4,'4',4.0})`

Comment: @Mikhail: `==` is not the same as `isequal`, so why would you want it to do that?

Comment: Nice shortcut syntax, less typing, technical progress! Why not?

Comment: @Mikhail: Because it would be inconsistent?  (Although cell array syntax is a nasty bolt-on already, I suppose...)

Comment: @Mikhail: `==` is **not** the same as `isequal`. The function that gets called when you use `==` is `eq`, as I state in my answer. Your actual question should be: _"Why is `==` not defined for cell arrays?"_ Well, the simple reason is: Cells were not intended for such use. If you _want_ to do it, I guess you can always overload the function.

Comment: @yoda: I saw your comment about overloading after I submitted.

Comment: @yoda: in your last comment you answer my question, thank you! Would you mind to edit your answer so that I could upvote and accept it!

Comment: @Mikhail: I have edited my answer. I've also removed the part explaining the syntax, as that was not what you intended in the question. Cheers :)